# Swiftui NavigationView back button overlay

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

im trying to create a clickable text which links to new page, all good but im having issues with the placement of the back button one new page has opened.

the back button is placing at the top but then pushing the rest of the content down, how can i prevent it from pushing the content down but overlay over the top of it?

[image][image]

in the second image with the back button the rest of the content is dropped a lot more because of the button

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            Color("background").ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack  {
                VStack (spacing: 36) {
                    VStack (spacing: 12) {
                        Image("Logo")
                        VStack (spacing: 4) {
                            Text("Welcome Back ")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                            
                            Text("Glad to have you back! Please log in here")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                        }
                    }
                    VStack (spacing: 16) {
                        AuthTextFieldView(title: "Email",
                                          placeholder: "your@email.com")
                        AuthTextFieldView(title: "Password",
                                          placeholder: "••••••••••")
                    }
                    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                        Text("Forgotten Password")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Log in")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        })
                        .padding(.all, 10.0)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                    VStack (spacing: 24) {
                        LabelledDivider(label: "Or login with")
                        HStack (spacing:24) {
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }, label: {
                                HStack (spacing: 16) {
                                    Image("google")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0)
                                    
                                    Text("Google")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                            })
                            
                            .padding(.all, 10.0)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            Button(action: {
                                
                            }, label: {
                                HStack (spacing: 16) {
                                    Image("discord")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 24.0, height: 18.19)
                                    
                                    Text("Discord")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            })
                            .padding(.all, 10.0)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color("discord"))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Text("Dont have an account?")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                    NavigationLink {
                        SignUpView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Register")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(24)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct SignUpView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color("background").ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack {
            VStack (spacing: 36) {
                VStack (spacing: 12) {
                    Image("Logo")
                    VStack (spacing: 4) {
                        Text("Welcome to Squirlz")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                        
                        Text("To begin, let's set up your account")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                    }
                }
                VStack (spacing: 16) {
                    AuthTextFieldView(title: "Email",
                                       placeholder: "your@email.com")
                    AuthTextFieldView(title: "Password",
                                       placeholder: "••••••••••")
                    AuthTextFieldView(title: "Confirm Password",
                                       placeholder: "••••••••••")
                }
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Register")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                    .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all, 10.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                VStack (spacing: 24) {
                    LabelledDivider(label: "Or register with")
                    HStack (spacing:24) {
                            Button(action: {
                            }, label: {
                                HStack (spacing: 16) {
                                    Image("google")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    Text("Google")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                            })
                            .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all, 10.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray5))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                        
                            Button(action: {
                            }, label: {
                                HStack (spacing: 16) {
                                    Image("discord")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: 18.19)
                                    Text("Discord")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            })
                            .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all, 10.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color("discord"))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("By registering you agree to our")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                    Text("Terms of Service")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("and")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("secondaryLabel"))
                    Text("Privacy Policy")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(24)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: in `SignUpView` have you tried:
 `.padding(.horizontal, 24)` instead of `.padding(24)`.
 If that is not enough, you could try: `.offset(x: 0, y: -40)`.
 Else use an overlay to display a custom back button in `SignUpView`.

Comment: You could use a custom back button, instead of the default one. See [NavigationBar item to edge of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77069023/20386264) for an example.