# UIBarButtonItem hit area (SwiftUI, but not only)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

So, like many other people, I've noticed that a `Button` added as a `ToolbarItem` with SwiftUI has a much smaller hit area than a `UIBarButtonItem` in UIKit. Or so I thought.

Below is a simple code to try the UIKit equivalent:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.navigationItem.title = "VC"
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .gray //TO COMMENT OUT
        let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Test", image: nil, target: nil, action: nil)
        vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = nc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

It produces the following "correct" behaviour:

[image: UIKit toolbar button]

As you can see, hit area is big, extends beyond the text and is comfortable for the user. However, if we comment out setting the background color of a view above (line `//TO COMMENT OUT`), we get the same behaviour as we observe in SwiftUI:

[image: swiftui toolbar button]

So, it looks like without the background we are getting the same behaviour as in SwiftUI – tappable area of ToolbarItem is too small and uncomfortable for users.

Yet, I have tried everything I could come up with and swill couldn't find a way to ensure that tappable are in SwiftUI is decent.

Does anyone know what the solutions could be?

It is an extremely annoying bug and I am receiving complaints from users :(

Comment: Would be helpful to see your SwiftUI code

Comment: This post might help: [NavigationBar item to edge of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77069023/20386264)

Answer (score 0):

Just for brainstorming

#### Crazy idea

Enrinching the button (UIBarButtonItem.customView property) with shadows, hiding the shadow with alpha =1 Therefore making the selectable area more larger?   Maintaining the alignment rect the same as it is now.

### More realistic idea

UIBarButtonItem exposes the width (instance property). set a desired wider size?
UIBarButtonItem  -> `var width: CGFloat { get set }`

### More unrealistic idea

modify customView of the UIBarButtonItem setting a new custom frame?

UIBarButtonItem  -> `var customView: UIView?`