# In SwiftUI or UIKit is there a way to override the padding/spacing the navigation back arrow has by default?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I'm looking for a way to override the spacing the back arrow has to better align with the content on the screen. For example, most of my screens use a `.padding()` or `.padding(.horizontal)` to move it away from the edges.

Ideally, in the navigation bar, I would like to use `.padding(.horizontal)` to ensure the leading and trailing actions buttons align with the screen content. Here is a picture for more context.

This picture has some text contained in a `VStack` that is using `.padding()`

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to hide the default back button to use your own?

Comment: Unfortunately, UIKit only lets adjust certain parts of built-in components, not including padding. You'll have to create a custom component instead.

Comment: @ElTomato, I was hoping there was a way to change the spacing before going down the route of custom.

Comment: @Stoic I see, thank you. I’ll go down the custom route at a later time then. It’s a nice to have but not necessary.

Comment: You could always use an overlay instead. See [NavigationBar item to edge of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071263/20386264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that custom after all. You would still use native modifiers, nothing fancy, like this:

```
NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
            Button("", systemImage: "chevron.left") {
                
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal) // <-- Padding as you like here
        }
    }
```

It does not seem all that "custom" to me, it's just an overlay like the others said. You could place the entire Appbar in the overlay, maybe creating a modifier you write once and then forget it's there:

```
struct AppBarModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    var title: String
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(title)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                    Button("", systemImage: "chevron.left") {
                        
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                    .padding(.horizontal) // <-- Padding as you like here
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And then using it like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
            }
            .modifier(AppBarModifier(title: "Title"))
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know your thoughts on this!

Comment: I forgot to add .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) to the content in the ViewModifier. I updated the answer adding that line so that the Appbar takes the entire width.

Comment: In swift, we call these [**custom modifiers**](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-modifiers), since they are not provided by apple by default